# Purge RecycleBin statement does not work in SSIS

Tags: oracle, plsql, ssis, oracle11g, sql-server-2012

I have an SSIS package that does maintenance work on my Oracle database.  As a part of this, I Purge the RecycleBin using the following command:

```
Purge RecycleBin
```

This command works correctly from SQLDeveloper.  However, when I issue the same command from SSIS (within an `Execute SQL`, it fails with this error message:

`Executing the query "Purge RecycleBin" failed with the following error: "ORA-38302: Invalid Purge Option"`

[image: Error Message]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo. Your error message says

> Executing the query "Purge RecyleBin" failed with...

Check your query, did you misspell `RecycleBin`?

Based on your image of the error message, it appears to be a typo in the query itself.

[image]

Try using the following query to extract the true text of your error message instead of using the pretty, but useless reports.

```
-- Find all messages associated to the last failing run
SELECT
    OM.operation_message_id
,   OM.operation_id
,   OM.message_time
,   OM.message_type
,   OM.message_source_type
,   OM.message
FROM
    SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages AS OM
WHERE
    OM.operation_id = 
    (  
        -- Find the last failing operation
        -- lazy assumption that biggest operation
        -- id is last. Could be incorrect if a long
        -- running process fails after a quick process
        -- has also failed
        SELECT 
            MAX(OM.operation_id)
        FROM
            SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages AS OM
        WHERE
            OM.message_type = 120
    );
```

If you know your operation id, you can paste that into the subquery

Comment: that was a typo when I posted the question.  If you look at the picture of the error message, it shows the correct spelling.

Comment: I did look at the picture of the error message and came to the above conclusion

Comment: SMH.. First `RecyleBin` then `RecycelBin`.  I'm going to need a spellchecker for my SQL code.